# Maximum Sum of Product

Tags: algorithm, sequence, maximize

I have a following problem.

Given N numbers, in range -100..100.

It is required to rearrange elements to have maximum sum of product value. 
Sum of Product in this task is defined as A1*A2+A2*A3...AN-1*AN

For example, given numbers 10 20 50 40 30.

Then, we can rearrange them following way:
10, 30, 50, 40, 20 from the left to have maximum 10×30+30×50+50×40+40×20=4600

The idea is to sort the sequence, and then put max number in the middle of new sequence, then put next max number to the right, then to the left, and so on.
But, regarding negative numbers this is not working.

I have tried following algorithm:

1) sort initial sequence
2) process positive numbers and zero values how described above
3) process negative numbers how described above
4) find minimum number from positive sequence, it would be either left or  right element and add after of before this number processed negative sequence.

For example, given sequence:

1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,-16

Expected maximum sum of product is 1342.

My algorithm gives next rearrangements:

3,7,10,12,14,15,13,11,9,5,1,-4,-8,-16,-6,-2

Sum of product is 1340.

This seem to work, but it does not.

Could you please advise?

Comment: How do you know what the maximum is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is sound, but you have to separate the positive and negative numbers.

Sort the array and split it into left and right parts, one containing all the negative numbers, and one containing all the non-negative numbers. Rearrange them as you were doing before, with the largest (absolute) values in the middle and decreasing values placed alternately on either side, but make sure that the smallest values in each part are at opposite ends.

Specifically, the negative number with the smallest absolute value should be the last element of the left part, and the non-negative value with the  smallest value should be the first element of the right part.

Then concatenate the two parts and calculate the sum of adjacent products.

Here's a worked example:

```
arr = [2, 3, 5, -6, -2, -5]
arr.sort() = [-6, -5, -2, 2, 3, 5]
left, right = [-5, -6, -2], [2, 5, 3]
max_sum_of_product = -5*-6 + -6*-2 + -2*2 + 2*5 + 5*3 = 63
```

I don't have a formal proof of correctness, but this method gives the same results as a brute force search over all permutations of the input array:

```
def max_sum_of_products(arr):
  from itertools import permutations
  n = len(arr)

  ###### brute force method
  max1 = max([sum([a[x-1]*a[x] for x in range(1,n)]) for a in permutations(arr)])

  ###### split method
  lo, hi = [x for x in arr if x<0], [x for x in arr if x>=0]
  lo.sort()
  hi.sort()
  lo_ordered, hi_ordered = [], []
  t = (len(lo)%2 == 1)
  for x in lo:
    if t:
      lo_ordered = lo_ordered + [x]
    else:
      lo_ordered = [x] + lo_ordered
    t = not t
  t = (len(hi)%2 == 0)
  for x in hi[::-1]:
    if t:
      hi_ordered = hi_ordered + [x]
    else:
      hi_ordered = [x] + hi_ordered
    t = not t
  arr = lo_ordered + hi_ordered
  max2 = sum([arr[x-1]*arr[x] for x in range(1,n)])

  return (max1, max2)

def test():
  from random import randint
  for i in range(10):
    a = []
    for j in range(randint(4,9)):
      a = a + [randint(-10,10)]
    print a,
    (max1,max2) = max_sum_of_products(a)
    if max2!=max1:
      print "bad result :-("
    else:
      print max1

test()
```

Comment: Did test with the second example given by the OP ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method in java that will take the array as an input and return the maximum sum of product pairs as output.

First I compute the negative part, then the positive part and then return their computed sum.
While computing the negative part, if the number of elements are odd, then the remaining element needs to be avoided (as it can be multiplied by 0 and nullified), we do this so that that negative addition will lower the sum.
All other negative items are needed to multiplied in pair and summed.

Then coming to second positive part, when we see 1 we need to add it if number of elements are odd, otherwise simply multiply and go forward.

```java
 public static long sum(int arr[]) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    long ans = 0;
    long ans1 = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    boolean flag2 = false;
    int[] arr1 = new int[arr.length];
    int[] arr2 = new int[arr.length];
    int i = 0;
    while (arr[i] < 0) {
        arr1[i] = arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (arr[i] == 0) flag = true;

    if (i % 2 == 0) {                              //even -6,-5,-3,-2,-1
        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j += 2) {
            ans = arr1[j] * arr1[j + 1];
        }
    } else {
        if (flag) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i - 2; j += 2) {
                ans = arr1[j] * arr1[j + 1];
            }
        }
    }
    int j = 0;
    while (i<arr.length) {
        arr2[j] = arr[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    if (arr2[j] == 1) flag2 = true;

    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        for (int k=i-1; k>0; k-=2) {
            ans1 = arr2[k] * arr2[k-1];
        }
        if (flag2) ans1 = ans1 + 1;
    } else {
        for (int k=arr2.length-1; k>1; k-=2) {
            ans1 = arr2[k] * arr2[k-1];
        }
        ans1 = ans1 + arr2[0];
    }
    return ans + ans1;
}
```